# Load subset of joined columns in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to load a subset of columns from multiple joined tables in SQLAlchemy and can't figure out the magic syntax.

Here's a simple example of what I'm trying to do. It results in an error (below):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, load_only

Base = declarative_base()

class Table1(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table1'
    table1_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    table1_val = Column(String)
    r1 = relationship('Table2', backref = 'r2')


class Table2(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table2'
    table2_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('table1.table1_id'), primary_key=True)
    table2_val = Column(String)


from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
some_engine = create_engine('postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost/')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=some_engine)
session = Session()
query = session.query(Table1).join(Table2).options(load_only('table1_val','table2_val'))
```

> ArgumentError: Can't find property named 'table2_val' on the mapped entity Mapper|Table1|table1 in this Query.

How do I pick and choose columns from these multiple tables?

Comment: Have you tried using `Table1.table1_val` attribute object, instead of just the string name? I'd expect SQLAlchemy to require a qualified name here, since both tables can in principle have overlapping column names.

Comment: Yields a different error:

`query = session.query(Table1).join(Table2).options(load_only(Table1.table1_val,Table2.table2_val))`

**`ArgumentError: Can't find property 'table2_val' on any entity specified in this Query.  Note the full path from root (Mapper|Table1|table1) to target entity must be specified.`**

Comment: Another variation, another error:  
`query = session.query(Table1,Table2).options(load_only(Table1.table1_val,Table2.table2_val))`    

**Wildcard loader can only be used with exactly one entity.  Use Load(ent) to specify specific entities.**

Comment: I've also tried the `Load()` route, which throws no errors but loads only the column from Table1, completely ignoring Table2's specified column:  
`query = session.query(Table1).join(Table2).options(Load(Table1).load_only(Table1.table1_val),Load(Table2).load_only(Table2.ta‌​ble2_val))`

Comment: The docs (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_columns.html#sqlalchemy.orm.load_only) say the syntax in this case would be `session.query(Table1, Table2).join(Table2).options(Load(Table1).load_only('table1_val'), Load(Table2).load_only('table2_val'))`. If that doesn't work, it's at least a documentation bug.

Comment: @Xion the syntax you suggest from the docs *throws no errors* but *does not work*.  All fields from both tables are loaded, not just the `table1_‌​val` and `table2_‌​val` fields.  
I am using sqlalchemy version '0.9.9'  
I'm going to try to figure out how to report the bug...  
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also fails on version '1.0.12'.  Still loading all fields, not just the fields specified in the `load_only()` calls.

Comment: Ugh: Primary keys are always added silently to the 'load_only' list. It's "by design" at this point. [(https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3080/load_only-omits-primary-keys-when-not)]. This is a problem when the primary keys have the same name.

Comment: Unfortunately the bitbucket link seems to only allow certain people (and not me)

Comment: Ah, github equivalent: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/3080

Answer (score 7):

Question was answered at [https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3679/multiple-load_only-in-queryoptions-ignore]

Here is the corrected code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import joinedload, Load, relationship, load_only

Base = declarative_base()

class Table1(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table1'
    global_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    table1_val1 = Column(String)
    table1_val2 = Column(String)
    r1 = relationship('Table2', backref = 'r2')

class Table2(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table2'
    global_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('table1.global_id'), primary_key=True)
    table2_val1 = Column(String)
    table2_val2 = Column(String)

from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
some_engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
Base.metadata.create_all(some_engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=some_engine)
session = Session()

session.add(Table1(table1_val1='1val1',table1_val2='1val2',r1=[Table2(table2_val1='2val1', table2_val2='2val2')]))
session.commit() # expires the attribute from the session

query = session.query(Table1).options(
    # note that the 'load_only()' is applied to the 'joinedload' path, not 
    # put on its own Load() path
    joinedload('r1',innerjoin=True).load_only('table2_val1'),
    Load(Table1).load_only('table1_val1'))

foo = query.all()
assert 'table1_val2' not in foo[0].__dict__
assert 'table2_val2' not in foo[0].r1[0].__dict__
```

Comment: Unfortunately the bitbucket link seems to only allow certain people (and not me)

Comment: Ah, github equivalent: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/3080